# Why can I not static_cast a templated object down an inheritance tree?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting

To be short:

- `Derived` inherits from `Base`
- `Holder` is templated to contains a pointer to anything
- I can tell that an object know as `Holder<Base>` is a `Holder<Derived>`.

  How can I tell my compiler?

This does not compile:

```
struct Base { };

struct Derived : Base { };

template <typename T>
struct Holder {
    T* point;
    int id;
};

Derived* d = new Derived();
Holder<Base> holder {d, 12};
Holder<Derived> specific( static_cast<Holder<Derived>>(holder) );
```

`error: no matching conversion for static_cast from 'Holder<Base>' to 'Holder<Derived>'`

This was a naive try for sure. But why does this not work and how should I get the `specific` holder I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Holder<Derived>` is not derived from `Holder<Base>`, they are completely unrelated types that just happen to be generated from the same class template.

You can create a `Holder<Derived>` that contains the right value:

```
Holder<Derived> specific{ static_cast<Derived*>(holder.point), holder.id };
```

Or you could add that functionality to the `Holder` class template itself by adding a converting constructor that does the cast:

```
template <typename T>
struct Holder {
    Holder(T* pt, int id) : point(pt), id(id) { }

    template<typename U>
        Holder(const Holder<U>& h)
        : point(static_cast<T*>(h.point)), id(h.id)
        { }

    T* point;
    int id;
};
```

Now your original attempt to use `static_cast` will work, because there is a valid conversion between them, or you can just write it as:

```
Holder<Derived> specific( holder );
```

That statement will compile as long as `static_cast<Derived*>(holder.point)` compiles.